# The value of 'this' in a callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code for doing an ajax request to a webservice:

```
var MyCode = {
    req: new XMLHttpRequest(), // firefox only at the moment

    service_url: "http://url/to/Service.asmx",

    sayhello: function() {
        if (this.req.readyState == 4 || this.req.readyState == 0) {
            this.req.open("POST", this.service_url + '/HelloWorld', true);
            this.req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
            this.req.onreadystatechange = this.handleReceive; 
            var param = '{}';
            this.req.send(param);
        }
    },

    handleReceive: function() {
        if (this.req.readyState == 4) {
            // todo: using eval for json is dangerous
            var response = eval("(" + this.req.responseText + ")");
            alert(response);
        }
    }
}
```

It is called with MyCode.sayhello() of course.

The problem with it is that "req is not defined" at the first line in the handleReceive function. It does get called 4 times, so I know the code above sends the request to the server.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Should be this.responseText .. not this.req.responseText (since 'this' refers to the XHR object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic closure problem. When you get the callback, the closure actually refers already to the HTTP object.

You can do the following as someone suggests:

```
var that = this;
this.req.onreadystatechange = function() { this.handleReceive.apply(that, []); };
```

OR just do the following:

```
var that = this;
this.req.onreadystatechange = function() { that.handleReceive(); };
```

Comment: Thanks!

For the record: working code is:
  handleReceive: function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4) {
    var response = eval("(" + this.responseText + ")");
    alert(response);
   }
  }

Answer (score 2):

You can solve that by makeing a variable refering to this in MyCode. Like

```
var MyCode = {
    req: new XMLHttpRequest(), // firefox only at the moment

    self = this

    ...
}
```

Then you can refer to self in stead of this.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
this.req.onreadystatechange = this.handleReceive;
```

to this:

```
var self = this;
this.req.onreadystatechange = function() { self.handleReceive(); }
```

This creates a closure that should fix your problems.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to make it work by changing

```
this.req.onreadystatechange = this.handleReceive;
```

to

```
var that = this;
this.req.onreadystatechange = function() { this.handleReceive.apply(that, []); };
```

Function.prototype.apply can be used to call a function while explicitly `this` and the function's arguments.