# XHR.readyState==4 && XHR.status==0 from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am having a hard time hunting for a bug. Consider this code (business parts removed to protect the innocents):

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState != 4) {
            debug("state was not 4, it was " + this.readyState);
            return;
        }
        debug("state was 4, status is "+this.status);
        if (this.status == 200 && this.responseText) {
            //(blablabla)
            handleSuccess();
            return;
        }
        debug("no response text..., status is "+ this.status);
        handleError();
    };
```

In the console, I end up having things like:

```
[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 1
[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 2
[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 3
[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 3
[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 3
[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 3
[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 3
[DEBUG] state was 4, status is 200
[DEBUG] no response text..., status is 200
[DEBUG] Handling error

[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 1
[DEBUG] state was 4, status is 0
[DEBUG] no response text..., status is 0

[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 1
[DEBUG] state was 4, status is 0
[DEBUG] no response text..., status is 0

[DEBUG] state was not 4, it was 1
[DEBUG] state was 4, status is 0
[DEBUG] no response text..., status is 0
```

How come I have such results?

Those are highly unexpected, and happen completely randomly. Some users see it, some don't. It is quite common upon extension installation, but works ok on browser or manual reload.

One thing lessens the frequency: this code is called using a window.timeout. If I call it through a direct call (using an other feature of the extension), it works most of the time (not every time).

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I suspect caching could be a reason. What happens if you add `Pragma: no-cache` to the response headers?

Comment: Are you sure you know what `this` is when it gets called, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839408/the-value-of-this-in-a-callback-function

Comment: While this is probably not related to your problem, it's easier to use [progress events](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#event-handlers) in Chrome (`onload`,`onerror`,...) than the `onreadystatechange` construct.

Comment: @MariusKjeldahl: I'm assuming this is the XGR object. amarite?

Comment: @brisssou It's a callback, so you do not really know what this points to when the method gets called. Use a closure, create a "var self=this;" outside of your callback, and then refer to self rather than this. I mostly use coffeescript myself where this gets handled in a different way, but the link I posted explains most of it from the javascript angle I believe.